# gorm-couchdb grails plugin and spring-security-core plugin integration

Tags: grails, spring-security, couchdb

Going to use spring-security-core for user authorization/authentication and site security. However, I'm thinking to use CouchDB as backend database (so couchdb users could authenticate through spring-security-core). Looks like we should create our own UserDetailsService and make it working through CouchDB. Same for user registation. 
Could someone just give me any references to start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a project [over here on Github](https://github.com/evilangelist/grails-spring-security-mongodb) for showing how to integrate spring security core with mongodb

Maybe it could be usefull as a starting point?